# various options in R (RStudio) under mac und linux

Tags: r, rstudio, lubridate

I have im mac:

```
library(lubridate)
> isoweek(Sys.time())
[1] 26
```

End in linux

```
> isoweek(Sys.time())
[1] 27

$version.string
[1] "R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)"  #  mac
$version.string
[1] "R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)"  # linux
```

Why? Where are options?
Thanks.

Comment: I think this may have more to do with differences in R version rather than OS's, because on Linux (CentOS 7) running R **3.2.0** I have **26** for `lubridate::isoweek(Sys.time())`. I didn't see any *direct* mention of it in the [R changelog](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html), but if you don't get an answer here will most likely get a response on the [R devel mailing list](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-devel-f909078.html). Also, for reproducibility it would be a good idea to include the timestamps you used `isoweek` on in your question.

Comment: `Rscript -e 'library(lubridate); (isoweek(Sys.time())); (R.version$version.string)'` gives me `27` and `R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)` on OS X 10.10.4 and `27` and `R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)` on a production server with a known good/working R install running various daily jobs. I think we need more info from you.